# Vector addition represented as matrix addition.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading this text:

[image]

I assume consistency is important here right? Like if you represent one set of addition as a 1xn row, you have to represent another set of addition as a row as well right? You can't represent u+v as a 1xn row and then y+z as a column matrix in the same equation right? Because you can't add a row with a column in matrix addition right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly, the notations are all equivalent, but (at least to some degree) you have to be consistent with them.

To be more precise, technically, tuples $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, row vectors($1\times n$-matrices) $\begin{pmatrix}x_1\dots x_n\end{pmatrix}$ and column vectors $\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\\vdots\\x_n\end{pmatrix}$ are all different objects living in different spaces respectively($\mathbb{F}^n$, $\mathbb{F}^{(1,n)}$, $\mathbb{F}^{(n,1)}$).

The important thing is, that these spaces are all isomorphic and thus, the different objects can be seen as just a change of notation. This has of course different advantages, like e.g. matrix multiplication is not defined for tuples, but through its identification with row/column vectors(matrices), equations like $Ax=b$ become meaningful.

The way you want or have to represent an object of course always depends on the context. E.g. for your question regarding addition, at least on a formal side, $(x_1,\dots, x_n)+\begin{pmatrix}x_1'\\\vdots\\x_n'\end{pmatrix}$ is not defined as they represents objects of different types for which (at least naturally) there is no such thing as addition.

Answer (score 0):

It's common to use $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ as shorthand for $\begin{bmatrix} x_{1} \\ x_{2} \\ x_{3} \end{bmatrix}$. Notice the change in the type of parentheses to help avoid confusion.

For the types of row/column matrices, I'm not sure exactly what you are asking. If one addition computation is between $1 \times n$ matrices, certainly another computation can involve $n \times 1$ matrices. We can add whatever types of matrices we want, and a piece of writing may include several types of matrices.

We *do* need to be consistent as to whether we are representing vectors in a given space $\mathbb{F}^{n}$ as column or row vectors, at least if we are going to bring any matrix multiplication into consideration.

Comment: But in a single computation like a+b+c+d, they all have to be a row or a column right? No mixing and matching?